# what is the last battle for the ultimate survival mode

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-3

In naruto ultimate ninja storm 3 is there a last battle for the ultimate survival mode? because i am at a 100 winning streak and im not going any further if there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

There is no last battle, it's just an endless mode where you fight until you die.